# Generating {$num} inside {foreach}

Tags: php, smarty

I working on smarty template.

I need to have numbers to my list array

So I tried

`{foreach}   {$num}   {/foreach}`

Which prints 0 1 2 3 4 5 ........

I want my numbers to starts from **1** & not **0**

How can I achieve this?

**OR**

Is there any other way to do it ?

**Thanks**

Comment: Simply use a good templateing engine! In Twig this would be `{{ num + 1 }}` or use the predefined variable `{{ loop.index }}`!

Comment: {$num+1} also did the trick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {foreach} {$num|assign:$num+1} {$num} {/foreach}

or

> {foreach}{assign var=newnum
>   value=$num+1} {$newnum} {/foreach}

Comment: `++$num` perhaps, since he wants to start from 1?

Comment: yea i think ++$num is not implemented in smarty but this should do the trick