# I want to auto generate serial number for rows. My given code is not working

Tags: php, smarty

I want to auto generate serial number for rows. My given code is not working

```
{if ($invoice.type_id == 2) || ($invoice.type_id == 3) }
    {foreach from=$invoiceItems item=invoiceItem}
        <tr>
            {assign var=number value=0}
              {foreach number=$var+1}
                 <td>
                   {$number}
                 </td>
              {/foreach}
         </tr>
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Comment: How doesnt it work? What is the actual output, and what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try solution from [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395439/generating-num-inside-foreach?rq=1)?

> `{foreach} {$num|assign:$num+1} {$num} {/foreach}`

Comment: try this one `{assign var=number value=1}
<table>
{foreach from=$invoiceItems item=invoiceItem}
<tr>
      <td>
              {$number}
      </td>
</tr>
{$number = $number+1}
{/foreach}
</table>`

Comment: Whenever i used to assign var it always show blank page

Comment: Blank page can appear when SmartyException was thrown. Maybe there is something in logs of your application?